# Adding Date Filter In BigQuery

Tags: date, events, filter, parameters, google-bigquery

I have a scenario where I need to filter my data for just 25th Sept 2021 - 26th Sept 2021.
My date column is a parameter called created_at.

Comment: add sample data and expected output.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the “between” statement to filter by date.
This is a sample code with this statement.

```
select * from [myproject].[mydataset].[mytable]
where created_at between [star_date] and [end_date]
```

This [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions) has more information about this statement

Comment: Actually my i have a parameter called "created_at" for the particular event occurrence and i have to filter the dates with that parameter.

Comment: i already edited the query with the correct field you use.